# GEE ee.Reducer.mode returning float values when input is integer

Tags: google-earth-engine, reduceregion

I'm running a [ee.Reducer.mode](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-reducer-mode) for a set of buffered points in a featureCollection with an input that is the esa Worldcover [dataset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/ESA_WorldCover_v100), which has integer values (10, 20, 30, 40, etc.).

This is my reducer:

```
var esawcReduced = ee.Image(esaWCImg) 
    .reduceRegions({
      collection: CTSbuffer,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mode(),
      scale: 10,
      crs: 'EPSG:4326',
      tileScale: 4 
    });
```

I was expecting to get the mode value for each feature in the feature collection, which I thought would be an integer matching the input dataset. This is the case for most of the feaures, but some features in the output .csv have a float value:

[image]

Why is this happening? I've tried messing around with the maxBuckets, minBucketWidth, maxRaw arguments to no avail. I'm not sure what I'm doing with those, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a large number of inputs, the mode is approximated from the histogram.  You may be able get exact values by ensuring that `maxRaw` is at least as big as the number of pixels in the region at the specified scale.

Comment: setting maxRaw to 9999 did the trick!